# In Rshiny, toggle between renderPlot and renderText

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

First, here's a stripped down skeleton of my Rshiny App, with what I'm trying to do (but is failing):

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Player Self-Centered Rating"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Chart Type"),
                   choices = list("RadarPlot" = 1, 
                                  "Separate Plots" = 2, 
                                  "Top / Bottom 5 Table" = 3), 
                   selected = 1)

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('radarPlot', width = 50),
      textOutput("text2")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  if (input$radio %in% c(1,2)) {
      output$radarPlot <- renderPlot({          
      ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(names, -ft_per_min), y = ft_per_min, col = this_player, fill = this_player)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")

      }
    }, height = 800, width = 900)
  }
  else if(input$radio == 3) {      
    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
      paste("print some text")
    })
  }
})
```

this approach of using if and if/else cases to determine whether or not to call renderPlot, or renderText, does not work. I get this error:

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Am I way off on what I'm trying to do here? Any thoughts on what is wrong, and whether I need this reactive expression or not would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `input$..` value can only be evaluated inside a `reactive` or a `render*` function.

You can do:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Player Self-Centered Rating"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Chart Type"),
                   choices = list("RadarPlot" = 1, 
                                  "Separate Plots" = 2, 
                                  "Top / Bottom 5 Table" = 3), 
                   selected = 1)),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('radarPlot', width = 50),
      textOutput("text2")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$radarPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$radio %in% c(1,2)) {
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, col = hp, fill = hp)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")}
  }, height = 800, width = 900)

  output$text2 <- renderText({
    if (input$radio == 3) {
      paste("print some text")}
  })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```